# How to group a set of data which are connected directly or indirectly in Tsql

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of data which are directly or indirectly connected, example data set shown below in myTable.
id b* and c* connected through c2 since they are all in the level 2 and/or 3; a* and d* connected since they are in either 1 or/and 2.  Since id a*, b*, c*, d* are all directly or indirectly connected to each other, so these need to be in one group show in myTable_result.

`Drop table Mytable`
Create table Mytable ( id nvarchar(10), level int)
insert into Mytable Values('a1', 1)
insert into Mytable Values('a2', 1)
insert into Mytable Values('a3', 1)
insert into Mytable Values('a4', 1)
insert into Mytable Values('b1', 2)
insert into Mytable Values('b2', 2)
insert into Mytable Values('b3', 2)
insert into Mytable Values('c1', 3)
insert into Mytable Values('c2', 3)
insert into Mytable Values('c2', 2)
insert into Mytable Values('c3', 3)
insert into Mytable Values('d1', 1)
insert into Mytable Values('d1', 2)
insert into Mytable Values('e1', 4)
insert into Mytable Values('e1', 5)
insert into Mytable Values('f3', 5)
insert into Mytable Values('f4', 5) `

My desired results:

`id  level   agroup
a1  1   A
a2  1   A
a3  1   A
a4  1   A
b1  2   A
b2  2   A
b3  2   A
c1  3   A
c2  3   A
c2  2   A
c3  3   A
d1  1   A
d1  2   A
e1  4   B
e1  5   B
f3  5   B
f4  5   B`

Comment: What a great job posting your table structure and desired output. The part that I don't understand is the business rule here. You state "directly or indirectly connected to each other", what does that mean? Why is "e1" in a new group?

Comment: Can you also post a sample of what you think the end result should look like?  That may help clarify your business rules for us.

Comment: @WesH the desired output is in the original post. It starts with "My desired results:". :)

Comment: @SeanLange.  Wow, I don't know how I missed that.  I must've blinked while reading down the page.  :)

Comment: hehe I figured you just missed it.

Comment: @Sean Lange,   Id’s connection is through level, if Ids share the same level then they should belong to the same group.
Business rule is this:  
c2 is in level 2 and 3 then group all the Ids in level 2 and 3 to one group A.  
d1 has level 2, then d1 is in the same group as c2 -> group A.    
d1 has level 1 as well, and in group A, so derived level 1 is now in group A -> all the id a* in group A too.
Since e* and f* has no connection with a*, b*, c* and d* in level, but e1, f3 and f4 share the same level 4 and 5, so they are in group B.

Comment: So what you have is adjacency list with multiple branches. Use a recursive cte to solve this. It is the exact same thing as an organization chart. There are millions of examples all over the internet and probably hundreds or more on SO.

Comment: The biggest challenge here is you have no real way of knowing what row to start with.

Comment: @Sean Lange, thank you for the suggestions, I followed your leads, but still can't get my head around it.

Comment: Why a1 in group named A and the other group B? I understand the logic of how to group the data but does the order of the groups matter? As I said before though, you don't have a solid definition of the root. Recursion requires a starting point and you don't have one of those.

Comment: You have obfuscated the real data so much this is nearly impossible. You have two pieces of data in the id column which is an additional level of pain here. Is that really how the real data is?

Comment: The order of the group does not matter, it can be named anything for the the groups.  Or you can think the 'level' is subgroup, and the group is supergroup.